# Why does my monitor changes colors when the graphics adapter changes?

Tags: macbook-pro, color, gpu

Whenever my graphics adapter changes, whether intentionally or automatically, i notice the colors changing.They get definitely brighter, more blueish when on the high performance card. 
Is this normal? Different graphics cards mean different color?

MacBook Pro 2.4 GHz (Late 2011) MBP Unibody 15"

- AMD Radeon HD 6770M
- Intel HD Graphics 3000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not normal, but a known issue. The problem appears each time your MacBook Pro switches to a *Discrete Graphics Card*.

There are a couple of things you could try, as a temporarily fix:

- Turn **Off** the *Automatic Graphics Switching* in **System Preferences / Energy Saver**, Reboot, and then turn it **On** again. This will make the *Discrete Card* to be initialized correctly. This *fix* will work, though, until your next reboot.
- Use [**gfxCardStatus**](http://gfx.io) to *force* the use of the **Integrated Card** only.

Some users got rid of it just by **Rebooting**, **Repairing Permissions**, **Upgrading to the newest version** or Reinstalling, though.

Comment: It seems its kind of random. Every once in a while I get a 'bad startup' and this happens. Thanks for clearing it up